# When is $\mathcal I\times \mathcal J$ an ideal of $X\times Y$?

Tags: set-theory

We say that $\mathcal I\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ is an ideal if,

1. if $A, B\in\mathcal I$, then $A\cup B\in\mathcal I$,
2. if $B\in\mathcal I$ and $A\subseteq B$, then $A\in\mathcal I$, and
3. $[X]^{<\aleph_{0}}\subseteq \mathcal I$ and $X\notin\mathcal I$, where $[X]^{<\aleph_{0}}=\{A\subset X:|A|<\aleph_0\}$.

Given $\mathcal I$ an ideal of the subsets of $X$ and $\mathcal J$ an ideal of the subsets of $Y$.

> > When $\mathcal I\times \mathcal J$ is an ideal of the subsets of $X\times Y$?

Where I can find the definition and fact about $\mathcal I\times \mathcal J$ as ideal?

Someone can give me any suggestions.
Thank you

Comment: What's an ideal of a subset?

Comment: Hi, Alex, I have already edited it

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but what is $[X]^{<\omega}$?  I wouldn't ask if I didn't think I could answer this question...

Comment: Rule 3 says: all finite subsets of $X$ are in $\mathcal I$, but $X \notin \mathcal I$.  If course it should be stated in words, not in $[X]^{<\aleph_0}$ notation.

Answer (score 1):

You never defined $\mathcal I \times \mathcal J$.  Is that the set of all $A \times B$ where $A \in \mathcal I, B \in \mathcal J$ ?  If so, your answer is: it is almost never an ideal, since a subset of a set $A \times B$ can fail to be of the form $C \times D$.

If you want something that is an ideal, you just say "the ideal generated by the sets $A \times B$ where $A \in \mathcal I, B \in \mathcal J$".  If that is the definition of $\mathcal I \times \mathcal J$, then of course it is an ideal.

Comment: Yes, the one in your last paragraph is the usual definition of the product of ideals.

Comment: But note that the definition of ideal given in the question is more strict, as ideals must contain all singletons and must be proper (that is, do not contain the whole set). That is, under that definition, $\mathcal I\times\mathcal J$ could fail to be defined unless you verify that closing the set-theoretic product under subsets and unions does not force $X\times Y$ to be in the resulting collection of sets.

Comment: Hi all!, I have asked badly I want to know that non-trivial ideals exist in $X\times Y$, I'm sorry

Comment: So ... Now is the time to re-write your question so that it asks what you really want.